# Java JPA error: Missing mapping for field

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans

I'm having problem with Java JPA with persisting entity relationship object. My table: *Rezervacija consists of (IDrez, idKorisnik, idKompanija, idKomponenta).* I'm persisting new object (and i got all 3 params after IDRez from database, and it's okay. p.s. idRez is being autoincrement by database.

Here's my code:

```
public class Komponenta implements Serializable {

@Id 
private Integer idKom;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idKomponenta")
private Collection<Rezervacija> rezervacijaCollection = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class Korisnik implements Serializable { 

@Id
private Integer idKor;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idKorisnik")
private Collection<Rezervacija> rezervacijaKorisnikCollection = new    ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idKompanija")
private Collection<Rezervacija> rezervacijaKompanijaCollection = new    ArrayList<>();
}

public class Rezervacija implements Serializable {

@Id
private Integer idRez;

@JoinColumn(name = "idKom", referencedColumnName = "idKomponenta")
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Komponenta idKomponenta;

@JoinColumn(name = "idKor", referencedColumnName = "idKorisnik")
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Korisnik idKorisnik;

@JoinColumn(name = "idKompanija", referencedColumnName = "idKompanija")
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Korisnik idKompanija;

}
```

// executable code part em - entitymanager

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

Korisnik korisnik = entityManager.find(Korisnik.class, 1);
Korisnik kompanija = entityManager.find(Korisnik.class, 2);
Komponenta komponenta = entityManager.find(Komponenta.class, 1);

Rezervacija rez = new Rezervacija(korisnik, kompanija, komponenta);

entityManager.persist(rez);
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

When I run this code I've got console out error:

> Exception Description: Missing mapping for field [komponenta.idKomponenta].

Comment: so you have different capitalisation in your table and your mappings

Comment: Here's my table structure:

Korisnik(idRez,idKorisnik,idKompanija,idKomponenta) should i change only referencedColumnName to these 3 last params in table - columns?

Comment: huh? You already quoted your table in the post, and I said you have different capitalisation in your JPA mappings ... i.e your table has a column "IDKorn" and in your JPA you put "idKorn" ... inconsistent

Comment: I've edited code up, i've changed referencedColumnName values, and now im getting:

Exception Description: Missing mapping for field [komponenta.idKomponenta].

Comment: I've solved problem, had a problem with manytoone and onetomany parameters. I've updated code to working one. Thanks a lot!